# Socket connection from Java to Objective-C

Tags: java, objective-c, sockets

I'm implementing a server push via a socket connection to an Objective-C based application. I'm at the point where I'm sending my data through an outputstream on the socket but I need to reassemble the data on the Objective-c end. At this point I haven't even looked at the objective-c IO classes and I am wondering how can I ensure maximum compatibility on the java end? I'm guessing I have to stick to primitive datatypes, am I going to have any problems getting back Strings that I stick into the outputStream? Most of what I'm sending will be strings that are more or less xml snippets/documents so if there's a better way to do this let me know! Keep in mind that my interaction on the socket is purely one-way. All the user-updating of my application occurs via standard Servlet interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to using a 3rd party library you could try [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) from google, there is a 'C' and java bindings so integration is pretty straight forward.

Otherwise your best bet is to stick to using `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` methods in particalar [readUTF()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readUTF()) and [writeUTF(String)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String)). On the Objective-C side a combination of `NSData` and `NSString`.

Unless you need the absolute speed and size you could get from doing it your self I would recomend using either protocol buffers or a higher level format like JSON/XML.

Answer (score 1):

Don't re-invent the wheel; passing a binary representation would cause a headache. I think using XML or JSON as an intermediary should work. There are many XML or JSON parsers available on Objective-C.